# How to check if a file is in a zip file before uploading to a webpage

Tags: file-upload, react-typescript

I'm using TypeScript to write an upload utility. Basically, it's just a div listening for a drop event.

Uploading uncompressed files or zip files works fine, but when a user drags and drops a file from **within a zip file** to my upload area, the uploaded file is corrupted (i.e. not decompressed).

Is there a way to determine if the file to be uploaded resides in a zip file? It would be nice to perform a check in my drop event before executing the actual upload. I can't find anything in the dataTransfer object.